# What does {+} mean in api variable types?

Tags: json

[![enter image description here][1]][1][![enter image description here][2]][2]This variable type was specified in an API. What does it mean? An object with properties?

```
webinar_id* {+}
```

It says string but when I input a string for webinar_id I get a 400 missing required parameter.

Comment: You'll have to do a bit better here. What api? Where did you see it, where is the documentation?

Comment: I've done that, could you help now?

Comment: The link you shared is behind a login page, as far as I can see on a quick look, there are * as well, if I were you, I would check what the * mean and potentially what you can see on the website. This is not a programming question as it stands, it's a request to help understand a documentation, without actually sharing a link where we could see this documentation. What help do you want? It also clearly states, it's a string. Couldn't you ask their support instead?

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation https://d3kcv4e58tsh6h.cloudfront.net/api/EverWebinarAPI.pdf

Comment: Did you bother looking at the documentation; it's right there!

Comment: You guys are missing the part I said "It says string but when I input a string for webinar_id I get a 400 missing required parameter."

Comment: When I use a string let's say g5457 on a request that doesn't have the {+} it runs properly. For instance a request to get a webinar, however for a request to create a webinar when I supply a string it fails so I'm thinking the {+} means something else(Not a regular string).

Comment: Sunday, that's just a statement, we haven't even seen your code, so it might be user error vs server error :p

Comment: I'm testing this using Postman so it's not code based

Comment: *{+} **webinar_id** and **schedule** must be obtained from a previous API call to retrieve the details from whatever specific webinar you want to register the person to*

Comment: I'm making a post request to https://webinarjam.genndi.com/api/everwebinar/register, them supply the details. From the doc, the required parameters are first_name, email, webinar_id and api_key I think. I supply those but it fails however if I change the post url to another it works just fine

Comment: I saw that, which is why I'm asking the question. It says string but I believe it means an object?

Comment: shedule is also required, take your time and read the document, read the fine print, * and ** and *** are all mentioned in the legend, under every table, why not do some investigation instead of jumping the gun and asking this kind of off-topic questions?

Comment: I've supplied schedule too, gave it a value of 1.

Comment: I'm not asking an off-topic question. All I'm asking is, what does the {+} mean.

Comment: I am curious, can you match your question with one of the topics inside the [help/on-topic], that would match the question you are currently asking? Also, don't give out that much  personal data, like your email address, IP, a big part of your api key. Development / testing is an art, take your time

Comment: It's just an indicator the author of that document chose to represent something. Based on the doc, it means that you must obtain the webinar_id and schedule beforehand. Pretty sure it's just that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [linked document](https://d3kcv4e58tsh6h.cloudfront.net/api/EverWebinarAPI.pdf) shows you that `webinar_id` is a string that is obtained by the call from section 1. Section 1 also specifies an array called `schedules`, and since the API call in question asks for an integer called `schedule` it is logical to assume this is the array of the index previously returned in the section 1 JSON response.

EDIT: `webinar_id` is also a string and `schedule` is also an int in the response from the call of section 2. I assume those will be identical to those from section 1.

The fact that `{+}` indicates re-using values from other requests is outlined in the subscript in section 3.

> {+} webinar_id and schedule must be obtained from a previous API call to retrieve the details from whatever specific webinar you want to register the person to.

Hope that helps. It mostly just comes down to careful reading of the documentation document (which you should be glad you have, things aren't always this explicit!)